# javascript date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-format

I am using jquery datepicker, I want to set min date and max date to show dates. I need to allow user to select date Within min and max range. And dateformat also I need to set based on the user locale.

And I have 2 date field Start date and End date.

```
$(function(){
                    var d = new Date();
                    var minD = new Date("12/02/2012"); //DD/MM/YYYY
                    var maxD = new Date("12/04/2012");//DD/MM/YYYY

                        $('#startDate').datepicker({
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear:true, 
                            dateFormat: "DD/MM/YY", 
                            monthNamesShort:getTitleMonths(),
                            dayNamesMin:getTitleDays(),
                            constrainInput: true,
                            minDate: new Date(minD.getFullYear(), minD.getMonth(), minD.getDate()),
                            maxDate: new Date(maxD.getFullYear(), maxD.getMonth(), maxD.getDate()),
                            changeFirstDay: false});


                        $('#endDate').datepicker({
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear:true,
                            dateFormat:getDatePattern(),
                            monthNamesShort: getTitleMonths(),
                            dayNamesMin: getTitleDays(),
                            constrainInput: true,
                            minDate: new Date(minD.getFullYear(), minD.getMonth(), minD.getDate()),
                            maxDate: new Date(maxD.getFullYear(), maxD.getMonth(), maxD.getDate()),
                            changeFirstDay: false});

                    });
```

But above code not working properly for another local country.... It always pick my system date format "mm/dd/yyyy".

So I try to format the date
var dateFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy";
var startDate = "16/05/2012";

dateFormat may varies, for example, dd/mm/yyyy, m/dd/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy etc.,. based on this startDate should formatted. have any need options other than split by separator?

Comment: Any chance you could rephrase this question?  I am very unclear on what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery dateFormat](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat) is a good plugin to use for this.

Comment: I try but I dont How to use.... try below code $.format.date("2009-12-18 10:54:50.546", "dd/MM/yyyy"); i am getting error date not define

Comment: You have to actually get (and/or load) the plugin. It's not part of the base jQuery package.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [this date formatter](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) which is a ninja of all date formatting.

Answer (score 0):

**add jquery ui plugin in your page.**

```
function DateFormate(dateFormate, dateTime) {
    return $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormate, dateTime);
};
```